# QGIS 2.18.12 REGEX Labelling Dilemma - Carriage Return

Tags: qgis, labeling, regular-expression

I'm having a drama labelling using RegEx in QGIS.

Ideally, what I want is the lines labelled WITHOUT the 'Spec' in the middle. Which can be a variation of numbers and characters but I need to retain the '1 x' and '24F'

EDIT; 'Spec' can be a variation of characters. e.g 'ABC123' it wont be the word 'Spec'

So the labels will go from this:

- 2 x Spec - 48F
- 1 x Spec - 96F
- 1 x Spec - 12F

To this:

- 2 x 48F
- 1 x 96F
- 1 x 12F

I'm currently using this in the **Expression dialog** window of the labelling engine;

```
regexp_replace( "value", (regexp_substr( "value", '[x](.*)?[- ]1')),'')
```

This works for the multi line values, those with a return. But it eliminates anything on a single line.

I need the single line values as well as the multi line strings.

Any pointers on what I could be missing?

[image: Table Example]

[image: Example of labelling using current RegEx]

Comment: What about `replace("value", ' Spec', '')` ?

Comment: Apologies if it's not clear enough, but 'Spec' can be a variation of values - i.e 'ABC12345'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression works on your examples (multi and single lines), on QGIS 2.18.3.

```
regexp_replace( "value", regexp_substr( "value", 'x( \\S* -)? \\d'), '')
```